# java matrix exp(A) calculating the exponential with a matrix

Tags: java, algebra, jama

I'm trying to calculate the function e^AT, of which A is a matrix and T is a double value. I have tried using both jama and colt/cern, however a have not found their respective functions. Could any one help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a matrix exponential in [jblas](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/). The method is called `expm`.
http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/MatrixFunctions.html#expm(org.jblas.DoubleMatrix)

The eigen library has an implementation of matrix exponential and also matrix logarithm and there is a Java wrapper called [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen)